# Console.log to html element - Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, object, service, console.log

Simple question. I have the following response from web service and I am observing it on chrome console. How do I deploy this onto Html element in angular 4? I tried to convert into JSON, but I encountered with another problem so I just decided to go with what I received after parseString.

All I want to do is, to display those fields in html element using Angular. For now, I just have component.ts file and trying to do something in html but can't figure out.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { parseString } from 'xml2js'
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

//import { IMovie } from './movie';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
    private urlNorth = 'service';
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getMovies(): Observable<any[]> {

        const headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set('Content-Type', 'text/sml');
        headers.set('Accept', 'text/xml');
        headers.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

        return this.http.get<any[]>(this.urlNorth, { headers })
            .map(res => {
                var result = res.text().replace('<string xmlns="service">', '').replace('</string>', '').replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
                parseString(result, (err, resultN) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return console.dir('invalid XML');
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(resultN);
                    }
                })

            })

            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse): ErrorObservable {
        // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
        // instead of just logging it to the console
        const errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
        console.error(errorMessage);
        return Observable.throw(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

[Log data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jm89.png)

Comment: Please provide more code of the service and the template(html)

Comment: Please refer to edited post. Thank you

Comment: @K.Son Y mean to show the content in template?

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

Does not belong in your service file. This is a component decorator and it should be on your component. Like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
   constructor(private _appService: AppService) { }

   getProduction() {
      this._appService.getProduction()
   }
```

}

Then your index.html file should use the  tag to display the HTML.

In looking at your code more closely, there are other issues as well. For example, you are calling getProduction two times. You should not be calling it from the service constructor.

Also, the subscribe should be in the component, not the service.

And you should be using Http OR HttpClient, not both.

And TestBed is only for use in tests ... not in services.

I have a more complete example of a working component/service here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-GettingStarted in the APM-Final folder. Consider looking through that code (or starting with that code) and making adjustments as needed for your application.

Comment: I am a bit confused, but I need to sort this out first. When I remove that decorator in service file and move to Component, I get this error : compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'AppService' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Comment: and I have seen a lot of examples, but it looks like most of them are dealt with local file they created..

Comment: Please provide a plunker with the code that you have so far and we can help you sort it out. OTHERWISE, consider learning a bit about Angular using the tutorial provided in the documentation here https://angular.io/tutorial, or a course such as this one: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update. (You can sign up for a free week.)

Comment: And yes, many use a local file to retrieve the data ... but the code would still be correct except for the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working service. (Without a plunker I can't successfully show this with your code. So you will need to make the appropriate replacements for your example.)

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { IMovie } from './movie';

@Injectable()
export class MovieService {
    private moviesUrl = './api/movies/movies.json';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getMovies(): Observable<IMovie[]> {
        return this.http.get<IMovie[]>(this.moviesUrl)
            .do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse): ErrorObservable {
        // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
        // instead of just logging it to the console
        const errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
        console.error(errorMessage);
        return Observable.throw(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

**Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { IMovie } from './movie';
import { MovieService } from './movie.service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './movie-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./movie-list.component.css']
})
export class MovieListComponent implements OnInit {
    movies: IMovie[];
    errorMessage: string;

    constructor(private movieService: MovieService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void { this.getMovies(); }

    getMovies(): void {
        this.movieService.getMovies()
            .subscribe(
                (movies: IMovie[]) => this.movies = movies,
                (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is IMovie that's being imported? and I don't have JSON data.

Comment: It's just the layout of the returned information. Do you have a layout of what is returned to you? If not, you can just use "any" anywhere there is IMovie and it will support any type of data.

Comment: Please refer to your code I updated. It gives me the error because my headers are not set properly. I get Cannot GET in chrome. I think it's because my headers are not set properly, but then when I tried to add headers, It does not recognize the options.. is it because I am suing HttpClient? It was fine with Http

Comment: You can see how to set up headers with HttpClient in the docs here: https://angular.io/guide/http or change back to Http. But don't use/include both.

Comment: Hi Deborah, I have updated my code in the question. I need to do parsing since I am getting XML from web service. However, I am getting error while using res.text()..